# Add a class to post title if a link ends with a certain extension

Tags: posts, css, post-class

I am using a [Page Links To](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/) plugin  that allows me to link the post title to an external web page, rather than to the content of the post. And I link some of the post titles to external pages, and others – to pdf files, stored in the uploads folder of my site.

I want to add a little pdf icon to those post titles that are linked to pdf files. To be able to do so, I want to add `.pdf` class to those post titles whose links end with `.pdf`.

Here's how the corresponding part of the page source looks:

```
<article id="post-123" class="post-123 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-news">
            <header class="entry-header">
                                <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="http://www.mysite.com/path/to/directory/pdfs/mypdffile.pdf" title="My WordPress Post Title" rel="bookmark">My WordPress Post Title</a>
        </h1>


    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <a href="http://www.mysite.com/path/to/directory/pdfs/mypdffile.pdf" title="1:19 pm" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="2013-04-23T13:19:30+00:00">April 23, 2013</time></a> 
            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->
```

What would be the best way to do that in WordPress?

Comment: How do you generate the post title markup?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Off the top of my head, my answer would be: "automatically" – but something tells me that's not what you expected me to say, @toscho. Please take a look at the source code I pasted in the body of the question - maybe that answers it in some way?

Comment: Yes, that’s a good step forwards. :) But we have to see the PHP code to suggest a solution.

Comment: Okay, @toscho – a php code for the Page Links To plugin – or php code for something else?

Comment: The PHP code that generates the content of the `<h1>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add anything via WordPress, you can simple add the following rule to your CSS file:

```
a[href$='.pdf'] {}
```

This will target all links pointing to a URI ending in .pdf. This works in all modern browsers and from IE7 upwards.